# Gulp watch, incremental build

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, build-process, gulp, gulp-watch

I'm struggling to make `gulp-watch` behave as I desire. This small project is tooling to build HTML5 emails templates from Jade+SASS, in a repeatable way. The directory structure is as such:

```
.
├── Gulpfile.coffee
├── Gulpfile.js
├── build
│   ├── hello-world.html
│   └── styles
│       └── ink.css
├── node_modules
│   ├── ...snip...
├── package.json
└── source
    ├── hello-world.jade
    ├── layouts
    │   └── default.jade
    └── styles
        └── ink.scss
```

My wish list is thus:

- Build all *templates* when **styles or templates** change. ***This is what I can't do***
- Don't have a seaerate "cold" start, always use the gulp incremental build. (This seems to work)
- Live reload would reload the browser, that'd be cool. (This too)

The `Gulpfile`, in CoffeeScript notation for brevity is included below, it's predominantly based on the documentation [Incremental rebuilding, including operating on full file sets](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/433c8686ac7abc97e3f70ffa4852712cc2a3c373/docs/recipes/incremental-builds-with-concatenate.md).

```
gulp      = require 'gulp'
inlineCss = require 'gulp-inline-css'
jade      = require 'gulp-jade'
marked    = require 'gulp-marked'
plumber   = require 'gulp-plumber'
rename    = require 'gulp-rename'
sass      = require 'gulp-sass'
cached    = require 'gulp-cached'
util      = require 'gulp-util'
watch     = require 'gulp-watch'
webserver = require 'gulp-webserver'

styleGlob              = "source/styles/*.scss"
templateAndLayouysGlob = "source/**/*.jade"
templateGlob           = "source/*.jade"

styleChangeHandler = (event) ->
  if event.type is "deleted"
    delete cached.caches.scripts[event.path]

templateChangeHandler = (event) ->
  if event.type is "deleted"
    delete cached.caches.templates[event.path]

gulp.task "styleWatcher", ->
  gulp.src(styleGlob)
    .pipe(cached('styles'))
    .pipe(watch(styleGlob))
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build/styles"))
    .on('error', util.log)

gulp.task "templateWatcher", ->
  gulp.src(templateGlob)
    .pipe(cached('templates'))
    .pipe(watch(templateGlob))
    .pipe(jade(pretty: true))
    .pipe(inlineCss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build/"))
    .on('error', util.log)

gulp.task 'webserver', ->
  buildPath = 'build/'
  gulp.src(buildPath)
    .pipe(webserver({
      livereload: true,
      directoryListing: {
        enable: true,
        path: buildPath
      },
      open: true
    }))

gulp.task "watch", ->
  styleWatcher = gulp.watch(styleGlob, ["styleWatcher"])
  styleWatcher.on 'change', styleChangeHandler

  templateWatcher = gulp.watch(templateGlob, ["templateWatcher"])
  templateWatcher.on 'change', templateChangeHandler

  # I would expect this to fire when something in build/styles/*.css
  # is updated by the style watcher?
  templateStyleWatcher = gulp.watch('build/styles/*.css', ["templateWatcher"])
  templateStyleWatcher.on 'change', templateChangeHandler

gulp.task "default", ["styleWatcher", "templateWatcher", "watch", "webserver"]
```

If it were possible, and I'd written this *watcher* in GNU Make or similar, I would have had the option to express that `build/`, and rely on the tooling to rebuild those files if the ones upon which they depend are out of date.

I've seen that there are a number of `gulp-<something about inlining>` plugins, but none of them make clear whether they support this conditional recompilation by watching paths that were imported for changes (I doubt it).

Given my background in systems programming, I may well be approaching Javascript build tooling in a completely incorrect way.

Comment: Can you try to get rid of the watchers into your styleWatcher and templateWatcher tasks? Your watch task looks good enough to me by itself (the templateWatcher and templateStyleWatcher can be merged in just one).

Comment: I copied all of that from https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/433c8686ac7abc97e3f70ffa4852712cc2a3c373/docs/recipes/incremental-builds-with-concatenate.md where there's a watch in "watch" and one for the glob.

Comment: I just read the recipe you're referring to: I don't see a reference to gulp-watch and it's usage in their "scripts" task. They just have a watch task that looks yours. Are we watching the same recipe? :)

Comment: Good catch, apparentlyI'm mixing styles from that and https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch/tree/master/docs#incremental-build